# Update post not working in wordpress - URL not found error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website.
My wp admin is working fine, I can use all the admin features. But when i try to update a page/post content Iget a blank page with this error
"The specified URL cannot be found. "
It was working well on friday. I have not changed anything in code or settings, but now it is giving this error.

Quick help would be appreciated.

Thank

Comment: have you check url after/before updating content?

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies, I have checked everything on my side. permalinks etc. 
Issue is found on server configuration. Server is blocking all the POST requests with  lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess this is a "PERMALINK" issue.
What you need to do is GoTo Admin panel: Settings->Permalinks->select "Default" or "Post Name". 
And then try updating or posting new post.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permalink as default from the settings.